# RedHat OS Upgrade - 5.5 to 6.5 is SSL certificate effected?

Tags: ssl, redhat

Doing an old web-server upgrade from 5.5 to 6.5 and was wondering if the existing ssl certificate (still valid) will be accepted by the new RedHat 6.5 OS

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. SSL certificates are not really related to the OS or OS version, at all. The OS doesn't need to "accept" the SSL certificate. You would simply configure your new server with the SSL certificate in the places you're using it (presumable in Apache for web service, possibly in other services, like SMTP in Postfix or Sendmail or POP3S and IMAPS in Dovecot).

There have been some changes to SSL that effect end users over the years, in terms of commonly used key sizes and the like, but it is a very slow-moving standard. Your certificates should be useful for years; we have some that have been in use unchanged for as much as five years.

Oh, one other thing: If you were running a version of OpenSSL affected by the Heartbleed bug, you would need to get a new certificate, regardless of OS changes. If you use the standard package provided by CentOS 5, you will not be affected by this bug. It was introduced midway through the CentOS 6 lifecycle, and never appeared in a CentOS 5 OpenSSL version.